# Can you avoid GLib variant references and memory leaks when using g_variant_get?

Tags: c, reference, glib, variant, gvariant

##### Background

I'm using GLib and variants.

I have this scenario where I want to get the value deep inside a variant.

The initial variant, `changed_properties` has the format `a{sv}`.

```
// Example 1
/* GVariant *variant = g_variant_get_variant(
        g_variant_get_child_value(g_variant_get_child_value(changed_properties, 0), 1));
*/

GVariant *changed_property = g_variant_get_child_value(changed_properties, 0);

// Example 2
GVariant *changed_property_variant = g_variant_get_variant(g_variant_get_child_value(changed_property, 1));
// Unref only frees g_variant_get_variant

// Example 3
GVariant *changed_property_variant_child = g_variant_get_child_value(changed_property, 1);

GVariant *changed_property_variant = g_variant_get_variant(changed_property_variant_child);

// Unref the objects and let reference counter get rid of used memory
g_variant_unref(changed_property_variant);
g_variant_unref(changed_property_variant_child);
```

##### What I understand

In my understanding, to extract `v` (which is a variant), I have first to extract the first `{sv}` from the array of `sv` dictionaries. In Example 3, I perform this in the first function call of `g_variant_get_child_value(changed_properties, 0)` after the commented code in **Example 1**.

Now I'm left with a resulting variant in the form of `{sv}`. To extract the variant, I have to yet again call `g_variant_get_child_value(changed_property, 1)` (Where index 0 is the string and index 1 is the variant in `{sv}` dictionary.

##### The issue

The issue appears when calling functions like in **Example 1** and **Example 2**. All the references of the memory obtained from `g_variant_get_child_value()`, `g_variant_get_variant()`, except for the last call which puts the reference in the variable, are lost and cannot be unrefferenced (as in **Example 3**).

##### The question

So my question is: How can one get to the depth of `v` and its contents without creating so many `GVariant` objects and handle so much memory through references?

Comment: GVariant is part of glib, not glibc; those are completely different libraries.

Comment: Thanks, but the memory rmanagement mechanism is quite specific to C

Comment: glibc and GLib are different libraries. It’s not that glibc is a C binding of GLib or anything like that. They provide completely different APIs and are provided by different projects.

Answer (score 1):

If you’ve been provided with an `a{sv}` you are likely wanting to look up a particular key (an `a{sv}` is the GVariant/D-Bus representation of a key-value dictionary).

To do so, use `GVariantDict`, which allows indexed access by string key:

```
g_auto(GVariantDict) dict = G_VARIANT_DICT_INIT (changed_properties);
guint value;
if (!g_variant_dict_lookup (&dict, "key-to-look-up", "u", &value))
  g_error ("key not found");
// value from v is now in `value`
```

You will need to know the type of the value in advance, and pass that as the format string (third argument) to `g_variant_dict_lookup()`.

Comment: This is cool. I am going to test it tomorrow. I wonder what time complexity the lookup has. With the provided examples I have O(1) time complexity, but I have to handle those ref counts. I'm wondering if there is another way. Good pointing out this. Many thanks.

Comment: `G_VARIANT_DICT_INIT` is O(N) in the number of changed properties. `g_variant_dict_lookup()` is amortised O(1).

GVariant is in general fast enough that you won’t be able to see its performance impact in a trace unless you’re running it in a tight loop or parsing tens of megabytes of data.

Comment: I'm parsing some sensors at 120 samples/second. I was leaking memory from this before and I was filling up about 150mb /minute. I will test this soon.

Comment: Let me know how it goes :)